# What's the policy on using the same answer to multiple questions about the same thing?

Tags: discussion, answers

I just found a new method to do [a certain thing](https://superuser.com/a/710735/203254) ... And excitedly wrote/pasted it to all the questions for which this is an exact fit. Then I started worrying if it wasn't the right thing to do...

You can see all the relevant questions and answers in my activity list, I'm sort of ashamed to actually tell their number here.

Is there a way to keep the answers but not (unfairly..?) gain reputation from all of them?

Answer (score 8):

If two or more questions ask the same thing, all but one should be closed as duplicates. If your answer is perfectly acceptable as *the* answer in two questions, those questions can probably be marked duplicate (unless the questions are subtly different, in which case, your *answer* should adjust to the specific situation the OP, and not be just a copy-paste).

Copying and pasting the same exact text as an answer to many questions is not very good site etiquette. You should *carefully* read the questions for each answer you post, and make sure that your answer is 100% applicable and relevant to the user's situation. If there are already answers by other users, read those answers, and make sure that your answer isn't redundant (i.e. just restating the same answer in your own words). If one of the existing answers is significantly upvoted or accepted as the answer, and something in your answer disagrees with theirs, you might want to take a moment to think about why your answer does not agree with theirs, and explain that as part of your answer.

Looks like you posted the same answer several times with very minimal tweaks. Some of the questions that you answered should be marked as duplicate rather than having more answers dumped on them.

Comment: I just flagged all of those questions as duplicates... However, also left a comment to request merge... Now what will happen when my answers for each gets merged? Do I have to now go back and delete those answers?

Comment: @MilindR I'm not sure a merge is always appropriate. This should really be reserved for questions that are 99% the same. In case we merge two questions we will of course delete duplicate answers.

Comment: @slhck I'm mostly talking about the answers. They're good, but spread across multiple similar questions. A couple of questions also show an exemplary amount of homework done...

Comment: Any deduplication drives happening on SU? I want those questions to get merged asap and be able to gain my rightful rep fast :)